# Express regex include characters after slash

Tags: javascript

I have the below logic in my code -

```
/myApp/:id - route to router A
/myApp - route to router B
```

I have the following regex in my code

```
/myApp/logs/:id(*)
```

Clearly if my URL ends with a /, it will end up going to router A, and return a 404 while ideally I want it to be routed to router B since it's valid to have a trailing slash. In other words, how do I write my regex so it ignores if it's a forward slash alone, and routes only if it matches everything after that in the id component.

Comment: Is it a pure javascript router or react, vue, or something else's router?

Comment: Pure javascript router.

Comment: Hmm, Can you use a "URL corrector" middleware that fixes wrong URLs and redirects them to correct URLs? Is it allowed?

Comment: No I don't want to manipulate the URL but want to handle the logic on my end to route it to router A ONLY if it doesn't have a / alone, but has id as well. For example reg myApp/ but accept myApp/123

Comment: You should escape `/` with `\\`. myApp\/logs\/:id(*)